# Robocopy keep copying "Modified" files

Tags: windows, robocopy

New version of Robocopy (in Windows server 2012) output shows it repeatedly (every run) keep copying files of type "Modified".

There are no obvious changes in source are destination files.

Can we know how what are these "modified" files mean and how to avoid copying again and again?

I need to mirror source directory to destination directory with all file properties (/COPYALL switch) with multiple syncs.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be known issue with the Robocopy utility version in Windows 2012.
More details below:
https://winadminnotes.wordpress.com/2017/07/18/robocopy-detects-files-as-modified/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/c5bc2af6-85c5-4cf9-b1de-9632e9696c57/robocopy-keep-copying-quotmodifiedquot-files?forum=winservergen

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/6eba1f81-8666-42ce-9aaa-e9cf8814c64f/robocopy-problem-under-windows-8?forum=w8itprogeneral